# Máquina nova e instalação do eclipse, maven e tudo do projeto java

Tags: java, spring-boot, eclipse, maven

Instalei o eclipse.
Java
Maven

Baixei o projeto

quando vou na opção maven clean, dá o erro:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.1.7.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.1.7.RELEASE.pom
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project br.com.ghsistemas.principal:principal:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT (C:\Docker\workspace\principal\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.1.7.RELEASE from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Failed to transfer file: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.1.7.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.1.7.RELEASE.pom. Return code is: 501 , ReasonPhrase:HTTPS Required. and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 19, column 10 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
```

[Meu arquivo settings.xml, está normal](https://www.guj.com.br/uploads/short-url/sNS5ByoXfPAjkrlxP3Kp0Vn57p.xml)

O que pode ser ?

A rede não tem  proxy.

Answer (score 1):

O seu `settings.xml` está apontando para repositórios http, esse protocolo não é mais aceito pelo maven central, apenas o https por questões de segurança, provavelmente só estava funcionando antes porque você já tinha baixado.
Altere essa linha aqui:

```
          <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>central</id>
                    <url>http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </releases>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
```

para

```
               <repositories>
                    <repository>
                        <id>central</id>
                        <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
                        <releases>
                            <enabled>false</enabled>
                        </releases>
                    </repository>
                </repositories>
```

Comment: Sim foi ajustado, mas por exemplo, tenho jar do próprio projeto e ele tenta buscar do endereço https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2.

https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/br/com/ghsistemas/utilitario. Este projeto não está neste endereço e somente local. Assim entendo que é errado.

Estamos criando um repositório jenkins.